# How to make excel cell have the same number of characters

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need Excel cells to have the same number of digits for exporting to text files.

For example, I need each cell to have 6 characters (i.e. the longest character value in a data set):

```
Original:      Updated:
0.00           0.0000
42.50          42.500
161.50         161.50
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly the same (for 0.00 it will not have the decimal dot) but maybe you can use:

```
=A2&REPT("0",6-LEN(A2))
```

This will show like this:
[image]

You can also make it go by longest character value in the set using:

```
=A2&REPT("0",(MAX(LEN(A$2:A$1000))+1)-LEN(A2))
```